# How to select data from 3 tables in SQL with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I got confused to select exact data from three tables. The data needs to select is more than 200k records.
I got

Table 1: **Header**

```
  No.    Code
  -------------
  1      AAA
  2      BBB
  3      CCC
  4      DDD
```

Table 2: **Detail**:

```
  No.    I-Code
 ---------------
  1      123
  1      122
  1      111
  2      222
  2      212
  3      333
  3      341
```

Table 3:  **Inventory**

```
 I-code  Code
 ------------
  123     AAA
  122     ACC
  111     ACE
  222     BAA
  212     BVC
  333     DVC
  341     CVD
```

I want to select **I-Code**, **Code** from **table 3** along with **Code** in **table 1** group by **No** in **table 2**. Is this possible? I tried many methods, it makes me more and more confused.

One of the query that I tried is

```
SELECT 
    inventory.I-code, inventory.Code,header.Code
FROM 
    inventory
INNER JOIN
    Detail ON inventory.I-code = Detail.I-code
INNER JOIN
    header ON header.No =Detail.No
```

It gives me the data but the No was duplicated. I tried to group the No also.

Expected Output.

```
No[from tbl 1]   I-code[from tbl 3]   Code[from tbl 3]{GROUPBY} Code[frm tbl 1]
   1                     123                   AAA                AAA
   1                     122                   ACC                AAA  
   1                     111                   ACE                AAA
   2                     222                   BAA                BBB
   3                     341                   CVD                CCC
```

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? what query do you have so far? give us at least one of the query that you've tried.

Comment: Hi I edited my query . I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Your query looks fine to me.  What is your current output?

Comment: Actually 1st table linked to 2nd table by **NO**. The 2nd table is linked to 3rd table by **I-Code**.  The **Code** assigned to **No** in 1st table got their **I-Code** in table 2. so In table 3, The **Code** must be same for the **I-code** that derived from table 1 and 2. But,My data base was key in with wrong values. So I need to found out table 3 with Wrong codes..

Comment: @Riya, what is your expected output can you please provider your expected output like your input table?

Comment: Hi I edited my query

Comment: you don't have `no` in your query. How are you getting it in your result ?

Comment: Re posting code questions please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using subquery and join

```
select x.*,y.code from 
(select a.no,a.code,b.icode from 
  table1 a inner join table2 b on a.no=b.no)x inner join table3 y on x.icode=y.code
```

Comment: X represent which table ?

Comment: its the combined table of table1 and table2

Comment: there's a missing dot in the selected fields.. should be `x.*`?

Comment: May I know about that x.* concept?  This one comes under which topic??

Comment: @Riya,x is just combined table on table1 and table2 and we named it as x after that we join this output with third table

Comment: Thank you so much once again.. U vanished my stress.. Just one click I took my 200k filtered data at one shot...Thanks a lot

Comment: @Riya, glad to help you :)

Comment: @fa06 Is there any possible way to update the CODE in tbl 3 , by combine checking the 3 tables? I just want to update my Code [from tbl3] with Code[frm tbl1](mentioned in expected output), as it got wrong data...

Comment: Can you plz give me update query in your answer ?     `UPDATE Inventory
   SET Inventory.Code = Header.Code 
  FROM Inventory, Header, Detail
 WHERE Header.No  = Detail.No
   AND Detail.I-Code = Inventory.I-Code`.. I tried this but its not working as per my expected answer@fa06

Answer (score 1):

you can use another query to get same result

```
  with t as (select   H.no, H.code,d.[I-code] from 
  Header H inner join Detail D on  H.no= D.no) 

  select  t.NO as [No from tbl 1]  ,i.[I-code] as  [I-code from tbl 3],i.code as  [Code 
 from tbl 3], t.code as [Code frm tbl 1] from Inventory I inner join t on i.code=t.code
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I got my answer, but still I go through and save ur answer too. 1 up vote for your answer  sir